# Does GIMP 2.7.2 exists for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gimp

Is there a precompiled version of GIMP 2.7.2 available for MacOS X? Both official website and MacOS version website show only 2.6.x for MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably don't bother with unstable releases — as Gimp 2.7.x are just the unstable development snapshots towards 2.8. Gimp for Windows is also only available as 2.6.11.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, development releases are only available in source code flavour.

You can obtain it through [FTP](ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.7/). You can also take a look at [its Git repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp).